# How show Login Problems with Spring 3 and RichFaces by AuthenticationFailureHandler?

Tags: hibernate, spring, jsf, richfaces

And Thank you for reading me...

I have an application with MVC Pattern with Hibernate, JSF2, RichFaces, Spring 3...

I have the login form working, but it´s impossible to show login errors... Why?

**application-context**:

```
<sec:form-login login-page="/pages/loginPage.xhtml"
 login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
 authentication-success-handler-ref="myAuthSuccessHandler"
 authentication-failure-handler-ref="myAuthErrorHandler"/>
```

**UserAuthenticationErrorHandler**:

```
public class UserAuthenticationErrorHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {
...
@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request,
     HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException ae)
     throws IOException, ServletException {

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken user = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken)ae.getAuthentication();
    request.setAttribute("error", "Can you Show me???");
    response.sendRedirect("......");

}
...
}
```

And finally the **login.xhtml** that *DON´T SHOW THE ERRORS* :(

```
<c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}" />

        <c:out value="${error}"/>

        <c:if test="${not empty param.error}">
            Habemus error
        </c:if>
```

**Any Idea**??? ***Thank You very much!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}" />
```

displays a session attribute published by Spring Security, so it should work fine.

With

```
request.setAttribute("error", "Can you Show me???");  
...
<c:out value="${error}"/>
```

you try to display request attribute. However, request attributes doesn't survive the redirect. If you need to pass a message over redirect, you can use session attribute instead:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("error", "Can you Show me???");
```

In

```
<c:if test="${not empty param.error}">
```

you check for request URL parameter named `error`. You should set that parameter when forming redirection URL:

```
response.sendRedirect("......?error=1");
```

Comment: Hi, Yes, that´s ok, but I have not the JSTL tag library on my project, only JSF2...

If I have not the jstl tag library, How can I write with jsf2 tab library the atributte "error"?

Comment: @ganzux: I'm not familiar with JSF. You can write simply `${error}`, but it won't be HTML-escaped.